# Definition of weak solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, parabolic-pde

I would like to define the notion of weak solution to initial value problems. Consider the PDE $$u_t - \Delta_p u = f \quad \text{on} \ \Omega \times [0,\infty)$$ 
with the condition $u(x,0) = 0$ and $u|_{\partial \Omega}(\cdot,t) = 0$.

In the book by DiBenedetto (page 21), he defines the weak solution as
$$\int_{\Omega} u\phi(x,t) dx + \int_0^t\int_{\Omega}-u \phi_t + |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u\cdot\nabla \phi \ dx \ dt = \int_{\Omega} u(x,0) \phi(x,0) dx$$
for all $\phi \in W^{1,2}(0,T; L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^p(0,T; W_0^{1,p}(\Omega))$. Note that $\phi(x,0)$ is not assumed to be $0$.

On the other hand, in the paper (http://users.jyu.fi/~miparvia/Julkaisuja/final_singularhigherint.pdf) in equation 2.2, he takes $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega \times (0,T))$.

My question is what is the right test function? Do I need $\phi(\cdot,0)=0$ or not?

Also what is the right definition of weak solution's to the above problem under the use of Steklov averages? Where does the test function exactly lie in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test function $\varphi$ is $C^\infty$ and has compact support, but its domain is not an open set. Its domain is
$$
\mathcal D=\mathbb R^n\times[0,\infty).
$$
So, $\varphi$ is compactly supported in $\mathcal D$, and thus its support could be any compact subset of $\mathcal D$.

Hence $\varphi$ does not have to vanish for $t=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just found a nice reference for this, Linear and Quasilinear Equations of Parabolic Type by Ladyzenskaja, Solonnikov, Ural'ceva on page 25.